# How to delete whole text from the beginning of a line with a certain string

Tags: shell-script, sed

I use `sed -n '/string/,$p' file >> otherfile` to copy text from a line with certain string to another file.

Now I want the copied text to be deleted in the original file. I tried different methods with sed and awk but nothing worked.

How to use sed to delete the text of a file from the beginning line with a certain string in it?

```
texta

texta1

textb    <- string, delete rest of the text from here

textb1

textc

textc1
```

or would it be easier to cut instead of copying with sed and what would be the command instead?

Comment: Please add some good examples and the expected output and format it as code. Like this it's difficult to get what you want to do.

Comment: Delete the rest of the *line* that matches, or delete from that line to the end of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **w**rite an addressed range of lines to a new file, and then **d**elete the range - the tricky part is preventing the `d` command from being treated as part of the output file name. In GNU sed, you can do that by splitting the write and delete into separate expressions using `-e`

**IMPORTANT NOTE: this will truncate `otherfile` rather than appending to it**

```
sed -i.bak -e '/string/,${w otherfile' -e 'd;}' file
```

Comment: I think that solved it! Still a bit tricky but good to handle. My workaround is to cut the lines to temp file with your code and after that i copy from temp file to estimated file with code "sed -n '/string/,$p' file >> otherfile".

Answer (score 2):

Or use ed!

```
ed -s file <<< $'/textb/,$w otherfile\n/textb/,$d\nw\nq'
```

Given your input **file** of:

```
texta

texta1

textb    <- string, delete rest of the text from here

textb1

textc

textc1
```

After executing the `ed` command, **file** becomes:

```
texta

texta1
```

(there's a blank line at the end that disappears in the formatting here); and **otherfile** contains:

```
textb    <- string, delete rest of the text from here

textb1

textc

textc1
```

The `ed` commands are:

- `/textb/,$w otherfile` -- write that range of lines to **otherfile**
- `/textb/,$d` -- delete that range of lines
- `w` -- write out the changed file to disk
- `q` -- quit ed

Answer (score 0):

If you use this command `sed -n '/string/,$p' file >> otherfile` to extract all the lines from the one **containing** `string` to the end of the file (`$`) to an otherfile file.

The easiest way to extract the complement of that is to complement the match:

```
sed '/string/,$d' file >> someOtherDifferentFile
```

And if you want/need to update the original file just copy the result back.

Which is what the `-i` option to sed does, so, this will update the original file:

```
sed -i.bak '/string/,$d' file
```